# How to Share File to specific email address

Tags: .net, email, windows-8, c++-cx, winrt-component

I'm develop a windows store app using winRT C++. I can share a file through email but it cannot specific a receiver email address. Bellow is a part of my code to sharing a file:-

```
DataRequest^ request = e->Request;
request->Data->Properties->Title = "Testing";
request->Data->Properties->Description = "Email With Attachment";

DataRequestDeferral^ deferral = request->GetDeferral();
create_task(Windows::ApplicationModel::Package::Current->InstalledLocation->GetFileAsync("testing.pdf")).then([this, request, deferral](task<StorageFile^> getFileTask)
{
    try
    {
        auto pdfFile = getFileTask.get();
        auto storageItems = ref new Platform::Collections::Vector<IStorageItem^>();
        storageItems->Append(pdfFile);
        request->Data->SetStorageItems(storageItems);
        deferral->Complete();
    }
    catch (Exception^ ex)
    {
        // Calling FailWithDisplayText() also calls Complete on the deferral.
        request->FailWithDisplayText(ex->Message);
    }
});
```

How can I send the attachment file to a specific email receiver without fill in the email address manually.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do that in Windows 8; you can either share the file (as in the code above) or you can send an e-mail to an explicit address (using `LaunchUriAsync` with a `mailto:` URI) but you cannot do both.

Note that Share Target apps can [ask the system to remember recent / frequent targets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh973050(v=win.10).aspx), so if the user has e-mailed **bob@foo.com** recently then that might appear as a direct option in the Share Picker. The built-in mail app uses this feature.

Another low-fi option is to [copy the e-mail address to the clipboard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh871366(v=win.10).aspx) and ask the user to simply paste it in when the e-mail app launches (or copy the file to the clipboard and use the `mailto:` approach).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But why we cannot do both in windows store app?

Comment: There is just no API to do it. Windows Phone 8.1 (which was released after Windows 8.1) does have such an API.

Comment: That's mean until nowadays we still cannot do both action in the same time or except that you have others idea to do it?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like all you want to do is create a new email message with a specific recipient. The easiest way to do this is to use the [EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.email.emailmanager.showcomposenewemailasync.aspx) API. I would recommend also keeping sharing as an option in case your users want to send the content using Facebook or Twitter instead.